# jQuery HTML namespace element click event

Tags: jquery, html, xml-namespaces

I have this code in my HTML document and I would life to bind click event on such elements.

```
<gui:button id="btnTest">
  <label>Compose mail</label>
  <click>someaction()</click>
</gui:button>
```

I tried this two methods in my document.ready function, but none of them work

```
$('gui\:button').click(function() { alert('clicked'); });
$('button').click(function() { alert('clicked'); });
```

Is there any other way to bind click event to such elements?

Comment: ...what is a `gui:button`? :) More importantly, how does it render on the client?

Comment: can u please post the resultant HTML markup ?

Comment: i far as i know namespaces in xml documents are declared like this xmlns:something="url" ... this is why i wrote namespaces ... and added  tag xml-namespaces on this thread ... dont question why i'm am using namespaces that way ... i just need it to work like this

Comment: i figured it out ... thanks for the help ... btw ... this application is for specific browser use ... so i can use non standard notations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding the event to the ID will be quickest:

```
$('#btnTest').click(function() { alert('clicked'); });
```

Comment: If the content is being dynamically injected into the page via AJAX then review the .live() or the .delegate() methods also.

Comment: I figured it out ... $('gui\\:button').click(function() { alert('clicked'); });

Answer (score 1):

Use two backslashes in the jQuery selector: `$('gui\\:button').click(...)`

(reposting Mitja's rather helpful comment as an answer, because it's too invisible otherwise)